# What are the types of errors you can encounter in Firebase completion handlers?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Almost all Firebase asynchronous functions have a completion handler which contains an `Error` argument. However for the longest time I've had no clue what these errors could be. Is there a place where all the potential reasons for an error are listed?

The reason I'm asking this is because I have this in my code:

```
try! docRef.setData(from: book) { error in
    completion(error)
}
```

I've marked it with `try!` is because I'm assuming the only reason `.setData` will throw is when `book` can't be encoded into JSON (or whatever format Firestore stores data in), which should never be possible in my code. This would imply that the `error` in the completion handler can never be "Failed to encode data". I would guess the `error` can only be network related issues but I can't say for sure because I haven't been able to find any documentation regarding the errors you can encounter in the completion handler.

If anyone can tell me about the errors you can encounter in these completion handlers please do. Better than that would be linking me the documentation where I can find all the info about these errors.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a bunch of errors codes that are used by Cloud Firestore:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Enums/FirestoreErrorCode

**Edit:** That link is broken. https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/handle-errors is the working link